# What does the notation "for t=T to 1,−1 do" in terms of time steps, in deep recurrent q network?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, dqn, notation

In looking at an algorithm in the paper [Learning to Communicate with Deep Multi-Agent Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06676).

Here is the full algorithm:

[image]

What does the notation `for t=T to 1,−1 do:` refer to in terms of **time steps**?

The network structure is a deep recurrent q network.

Secondly, why do the gradients need to be reset to zero?

Comment: That notation should mean to go from time step $T$ to time step $1$ by a negative step $-1$, i.e. backward, so $T$, then $T-1$, then $T-2$, and so on until $1$. If you know Python, this should be familiar. However, note that this is just a guess because I am not familiar with this algorithm.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, and fits the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That notation should mean to go from time step $T$ to time step $1$ by a negative step $-1$, i.e. backward, so $T$, then $T-1$, then $T-2$, and so on until $1$. If you know Python, this should be familiar. However, note that this is just a guess, because I am not familiar with this algorithm.